# Add/Drop Column conditionally MySQL

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, information-schema

I'm trying to insert a column into a table if it's not already there. Anything like `DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS` isn't working (both dropping and adding a column doesn't work), apparently because my MySQL version does not support these kind of if conditions.
My question is, is it possible to insert a column into a table based on a `CASE` statement ?

I've already figured out how to determine if a column exists, but I'm struggling to insert a column based on this condition.

The `case statement` I would like to have working would look something like this:

```
    CASE WHEN    (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='PSIP-1.Standardproject_V2.5_notvalid'
                 AND TABLE_NAME='PS_Relevant Rail Stations$Loc'
                 AND COLUMN_NAME='triade') 
    IS NULL THEN 
    ALTER TABLE PS_Relevant Rail Stations$Loc
    ADD COLUMN triade;
```

I'm also not sure where to put this `CASE statement`, as this code wouldn't work by itself. Do I need to begin with `UPDATE PS_Relevant Rail Stations$Loc` and then continue with `CASE`?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this functionality using a stored procedure, which takes as inputs the db name, table name, column name and column definition and if the column name doesn't exist in the specified table, creates a dynamic SQL statement to create it. For example:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_column_if_not_exists //

CREATE PROCEDURE add_column_if_not_exists(IN dbname VARCHAR(50), 
                                          IN tblname VARCHAR(50), 
                                          IN colname VARCHAR(50),
                                          IN coltype VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=dbname
                 AND TABLE_NAME=tblname
                 AND COLUMN_NAME=colname) THEN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', dbname, '`.`', tblname, '` ADD COLUMN `', colname, '` ', coltype);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

You would then call this procedure like this (modifying the column definition as appropriate)

```
CALL add_column_if_not_exists('PSIP-1.Standardproject_V2.5_notvalid',
                              'PS_Relevant Rail Stations$Loc',
                              'triade',
                              'INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0')
```

Note that if you have a specific case only e.g. it's always the same column in the same table, you can just hard code those values in the queries and remove the corresponding input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and this question helped me find an answer. I made a more general-purpose solution, and it might be useful especially in situations where CREATE PROCEDURE is not practical or permitted.

This snippet drops a column but you can adapt it to create one. Replace $tablename and $columnname with your table name and column name.

It generates different SQL depending on whether or not the column exists.

```
SET @sql = (SELECT IF(
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() 
    AND TABLE_NAME='$tablename' AND COLUMN_NAME='$columnname'
    ) = 0,
  'SELECT 1', -- (noop, for when the column does not exist)
  'ALTER TABLE $tablename DROP $columnname'  
));
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```